# Can't click a button inside a <td> element

Tags: python, html, selenium

#This issue was resolved becouse it was an iframe issue, that's why the element couldn't be found, the code I used to make it work is:

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary")
```

I have the following html code:

```
<td>                        
<input type="hidden" value="xxxxx" id="1_nombre_77074118_1">
<input type="hidden" value="xxx@xxx.cl" id="1_email_77074118_1">
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="" onclick="javascript:submitEntrar(true,1,77074118,'1');return false;">Ingresar como usuario</a>
</td>
```

I need to click the class="btn btn-primary / Ingresar como usuario" button, but can't seem to find the element?

This is my code:

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn-primary")
print(len(button))
for b in button:
    print(button)
```

(Both print's don't return element's becouse they where not found).

I also tried by XPATH but it didin't work, this is the XPATH:

```
//*[@id="container"]/section/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a
```

Full XPATH:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/section/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all since there are multiple class names in the element instead of

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn btn-primary")
```

Try

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary")
```

Also you possibly have to add delay / wait before accessing these elements.

Comment: Hiho, thanks for the help, I tried the following:                                                                                `time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary")
print(len(button))`                                                                                                                         It didin't work.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? The length is 0?

Comment: Yes, the length is 0.

Comment: Well, I need to see the web page to see what happens there.

Comment: Now it works!! I had a iframe issue, thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary)
```

Comment: Why? You should add some explanation as to what this code does and why it should work. Code only answers are frowned upon on SO and "Try" doesn't count... ;)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this as we can search and click on the element based on the text

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Ingresar como usuario']")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text()='Ingresar como usuario')]")

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Ingresar como usuario")
```

Also, recommend using `explicitWait`

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Ingresar como usuario']")))

button.click()
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because of two reasons

1. Class call should prepend with . Eg) `.btn`
2. You are trying to call with two classes. If you notice `btn` and `btn-primary` are two different classes, so you could call using either

`button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-primary")`

Or

`button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(".btn.btn-primary")`

Comment: Hello, your first solution still prints 0, no element found, the second shows the following error: `button = driver.find_element_by_class_name(".btn.btn-primary")` `An invalida or illegal selector was specified`

Comment: If you are using `find_elements_by_class_name()`, you don't need the `.`. `.` is CSS selector syntax.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry. I missed to mention "or" between.

```find_elements_by_class_name``` accepts only one class name and not multiple. So, you can go with either ```button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn")``` Or ```button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("btn-primary")```.

However, you can use ```find_elements_by_xpath``` or ```find_element_by_css_selector``` for multiple class names.

Comment: You should still edit your answer to make the correction.